# CQWP throwing security validation error when selecting list

Tags: content-query-web-part, forms-authentication

I am currently building an intranet portal which is highly dependent on content query web parts. I am having an issue where when I go to select a list from the popup, it throws an error.

[image: This is how the CQWP looks right before clicking on a list.]

[image: This is after clicking on a list.]

The error in the 14 hive LOGS is the following.

```
05/31/2012 13:54:19.26  w3wp.exe (0x085C)                           0x15E0  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (POST:http://intranet-prod:80/AboutUs/Brand/_layouts/PickerTreeView.aspx?title=CbqPickerSelectListTitle&text=CbqPickerSelectListText&filter=websLists&root=&selection=&featureId=&errorString=&iconUrl=/_layouts/images/smt_icon.gif&scopeToWeb=&requireCT=&sourceId=) e78e82d6-e6bd-4bfb-a489-e0eb832e4b67
05/31/2012 13:54:19.26  w3wp.exe (0x085C)                           0x15E0  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  e78e82d6-e6bd-4bfb-a489-e0eb832e4b67
05/31/2012 13:54:19.28  w3wp.exe (0x085C)                           0x15E0  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8kh7    High        The security validation for this page has timed out. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.    e78e82d6-e6bd-4bfb-a489-e0eb832e4b67
05/31/2012 13:54:19.28  w3wp.exe (0x085C)                           0x15E0  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The security validation for this page has timed out. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ValidateFormDigest(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ValidateFormDigest(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName)   e78e82d6-e6bd-4bfb-a489-e0eb832e4b67
05/31/2012 13:54:19.28  w3wp.exe (0x085C)                           0x15E0  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://intranet-prod:80/AboutUs/Brand/_layouts/PickerTreeView.aspx?title=CbqPickerSelectListTitle&text=CbqPickerSelectListText&filter=websLists&root=&selection=&featureId=&errorString=&iconUrl=/_layouts/images/smt_icon.gif&scopeToWeb=&requireCT=&sourceId=)). Execution Time=22.8274822638073   e78e82d6-e6bd-4bfb-a489-e0eb832e4b67
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it is really not possible to see the small screendumps you have attached. Try instead to describe what you are doing and with what tools

Comment: Sorry for the image sizes being small, I think you can just change the browser settings to >100% to see them more clearly. Basically I have a few lists and I'm trying to use those with the CQWP. But When i go to select the list, it throws that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular error happens a lot when you use the Back button during page edit sessions (don't do that) or if you start editing the page as one user ID but then authenticate as another user while the edit is in process.

To get around all of those, close all browser windows and then open the site in a single window.  Authenticate with whatever user ID you need in order to make the edits.  Then start editing the page and only use the buttons provided in SharePoint for navigation while editing.

I have also seen this happen with when there was a misbehaving web part on the page that was invalidating View State so if you have custom web parts on that page, you might want to check their code.

Comment: We put a CQWP on a completely new site collection with no new features added and it still does the same thing. When we did it in the new site collection, only 1 users was editing the CQWP. Even with that, it was not letting us select a list. Another thing it does is it also won't let me select the right list. If i click a list, it highlights another list.

Comment: Do you have any sort of middle-tier caching or reverse proxy hardware in place?  This almost sounds like there is partial caching of page output happening.  Perhaps a load balancer?

Comment: Yes there are loadbalancers in our production servers and this is where the error keeps happening. There are no loadbalancers in our QA or DEV environments. The error is not happening there. Do the load balancers have anything to do with this?

Comment: Quite possibly.  If you can, see if the people in charge of the load balancers can enable "sticky" or persistent sessions (that is, once a user hits a particular server, all of their future requests go to that server)  This is technically less balanced but would only be noticeable on high volume sites.  You also might want to ask them if they have caching enabled at that tier.  If they do, that can cause this as well.

Comment: Thanks, this issue was caused by caching on the loadbalancers. Once they are configured, it should work normally.